# Adding a column to a Google Earth Engine feature collection and add names to it using ID

Tags: google-earth-engine, field-calculator, labeling

I am new to Google Earth Engine(GEE) and I think my question may have a very simple answer. We can easily assign names to a point shape file by using Arcmap and Field Calculator but I don't know how to do that in GEE. I created a buffer from a watershed boundary and then create points from the center of 'ERA5-Land Hourly - ECMWF Climate Reanalysis' pixels in that boundary. I tried to create a column named "Name" in that point feature collection and want to assign ("A" +(ID +1)) to each point. IDs started from 0, so I want to add 1 to each one and start from "A1".
For example, I have 35 Points, so I should have A1 to A35 for the points.

It is possible to see my code as below:

[My Code:](https://code.earthengine.google.com/1e258c8719381cc7f68ca011530ecf35)

```
var output1 = ee.FeatureCollection(output);
var outputname =
  output1.map(function (feature) {
    var id = feature.get(ID).add(1)
    return feature.set('Name', "A" + id);
  });
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Please take the [tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) and edit your question. Please ask one question a post before it gets closed

Answer (score 2):

First, since you are new to GEE, I strongly recommend you to look [Client vs. Server](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/client_server). I was super lost until I read that guide.

So if you're mapping over a `ee.` object, use server-side functions.

First, `get()` expects a string as argument, so if `ID` doesn't contain `'ID'` value, the code won't work.

For your case, when you pull `ID` property, the result is a number. You should convert it to a server-side object (`ee.Number`). `.add()` is a server-side function, that's why is not working in your current code.

Then, if you want to concatenate a string with above result, use a `ee.String` object and a server-side function to concatenate both values:

```
var outputname =
  output1.map(function (feature) {
    var id = ee.String("A").cat(ee.String(ee.Number(feature.get('ID')).add(1)))
    return feature.set('Name', id);
  });
```